# Single img element maintaining enforced aspect ratio without wrapper padding hack

Tags: html, css

Looking for a technique for controlling an  tag's aspect ratio. aspect-ratio property isn't supported enough for use at the time of this post.

Generally I would wrap the element in a a container and apply a padding top to create the effect needed. However, the content this I have is inline with other content and I can't touch the html.

The container width that the image is responsive so enforcing height and width directly isn't an option.

For example having an image keep 16:9 ratio within a container. It doesn't matter about the visual scale of the image. I will get the image to adjust with

```
object-fit: cover
```

Is there a current technique that would work on just the img tag itself?

Answer (score 1):

It is an aspect ratio problem. Unfortunately CSS on `img` tag to use the aspect-ratio technique needs a `div` container. I had a similar problem that I solved using css as soon as:

```css
.img {
    display: table-cell; 
    max-width: ...; 
    max-height: ...; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use the padding tweak, I assume that you can't use javascript either.
If you are only able to work on the img tag, the only solution I'd see that would be close to what you aim to achieve would be :

```
.yourImage {
    width : 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: Right. No js either.

I realised I need to add some clarify in the description and title. I need to maintain an aspect ratio of my choosing. So I need to force 1:1 or 16:9 etc... regardless of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You could decide width based on the viweport, as

```
.theImage {
  width: 20vh;
  height: auto;
}
```

or some other variation of it.